# How to create CSV/Excel of schema.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, schema

I want to create a CSV/Excel file from db/schema.rb file. I am able to dump the table name and their attribute names in a file, but I also want to dump other information like indexes, and constraints on columns etc.

Here is my code

```
require 'write_xlsx'
Rails.application.eager_load!
# Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = WriteXLSX.new('schema.xlsx')

# Add a worksheet
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

# Add and define a format
format = workbook.add_format # Add a format
format.set_bold
format.set_color('red')
format.set_align('center')

# Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
col = row = 0
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Table Name')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Attributes')
worksheet.write(0, 2, 'Attribute Type')
worksheet.write(0, 3, 'Attribute constraints')
worksheet.write(0, 4, 'Comments')
ApplicationRecord.descendants.each_with_index do |model, _index|
  row += 1
  worksheet.write(row, 0, model.name)
  worksheet.write(row, 1, '')
  model.attribute_types.each_pair do |attribute, attribute_type|
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, 1, attribute)
    worksheet.write(row, 2, attribute_type.type)
    worksheet.write(row, 3, JSON.parse(attribute_type.to_json))
  end
end

workbook.close
```

I also tried this from PG admin but got expected result.

```
COPY (select * from information_schema.columns) TO '/home/sachin/ruby/profile_service/columns.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header;
```

Comment: Do you need a programmatic solution? If not, you could use a tool like Postico to run the query `select * from information_schema.columns`, and then export the results to CSV.

Comment: @aridlehoover yes I need a programmatic solution. which will show constraints and indexes along with the columns of the table.

Comment: I'd highly suggest getting familiar with ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a simple "export_to_csv" method you can use but if you want to extend your approach collecting all the database information through ActiveRecord than I think in [schema_dumper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb) you will find everything you need. Just follow how `SchemaDumper#dump` collects all the information.

You can get a `SchemaDumper` object with

```
connection = ApplicationRecord.connection
dumper = connection.create_schema_dumper({})
```

A way to get index information for a table seems to be:

```
table = connection.tables.first
connection.indexes(table)
```

`SchemaDumper.column_spec` is probably also useful for your use case:

```
column = connection.columns(table).first
dumper.send(:column_spec, column) # => [:integer, {:null=>"false", :auto_increment=>"true"}]
```